Can two EventGrid Subscriptions be triggered by a single `BlobCreated` action?
Can two (or more) EventGrid Subscriptions (from the same EventGrid System Topic or different topics) be triggered by a single CreateBlob event?

Example:

File is uploaded to a Blob Storage Container
This generates a CreateBlob event that the System Topic watching
Two EventGrid Subscriptions will create a Queue message
If the Subscriptions have a filter set to /container_name, will both EventGrid Subscriptions create an EventGrid Queue message to their respective Queue endpoints?

Or is it first-come-first-serve, meaning will only one Event Subscription generate a queue message?
(PS: Looks like imgur is failing at hosting images. I tried 2x)


Can two EventGrid Subscriptions be triggered by a single BlobCreated action?

Yes, it will triggered in both subscriptions and it will also send messages to queue and below are my observations:
Firstly, uploaded a blob:

Then I have configured both subscriptions in a single topic and then checked the messages:
Configured different queues for different subscriptions to test:
First queue:

Second queue:

So by above observation, you can clearly see that it got triggered two times for different subscriptions

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@RithwikBojja, I wish I could see the images you created.

Sure @ericOnline, https://i.imgur.com/jnTVKTy.png
